# "ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded" - Linux Mint 20 Ulyana

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, nvidia, graphic-card

I have installed Linux Mint 20 Ulyana, with secure boot enabled, on my Mi Horizon 14 notebook equipped with Geforce MX350. After the installation I have enabled `nvidia-driver-440` using Driver Manager. However, when I issue `sudo nvidia-setttings` in terminal I get the following error message.

```
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system.
(nvidia-settings:1702): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 23:31:25.342: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 23:31:25.343: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 23:31:25.343: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

The output of `nvidia-bug-report.sh` can be [found here](https://share.riseup.net/#8EOhxZSAtLxdoTpbfv6SpQ) if it helps to resolve this issue.

Update 1: Attaching the output of `sudo modprobe nvidia`

`modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Operation not permitted`

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `dmesg | grep -i nvidia`

Comment: I do not get any output when I issue that.

Comment: Do you have secure boot enabled?

Comment: Yes. I have secure boot enabled.

Comment: I think you need signed modules with secure boot, but I don't know the details.  That's likely why the `nvidia` module isn't loading.

Comment: Thank you @AndyDalton: Let me search and try that.